# Devise authentication - custom user edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :registrations => 'users',
  :sessions => 'sessions',
  :confirmations => 'confirmations',
  :passwords => 'passwords'
}
```

The view for "edit" action:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<%= resource.inspect %>
```

resource.inspect shows all user's fields as nil.

Controller:

```
def edit
  resource = params[:id].nil? ? current_user : User.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

What to put instead of "resource =" to make this thing work? I want that the view remains with default "resource" and "resource_name" variables.

**IMPORTANT: I would prefer to retain the default behaviour for edit method without overriding it and without writing own code for it.**

Comment: not sure of what you want, but seems you should use an instance variable: `@resource`

Comment: The solution was to inherit the Users controller from Devise::RegistrationsController and to use "super" in "def edit"

Comment: I guess they declare the 'resource' as helper method there

Comment: I encountered another problem: I can edit current user with root/users/edit URL, but can't do this for other user account with root/users/2/edit URL. I get "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: The "undefined method 'name'" error resides in gems/devise-2.0.4/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb in "def devise_mapping".